# Factory em angular para inserir dados no banco

Tags: php, angularjs

Como crio uma função, em factory, para inserir dados no banco?
Tenho isso:

```
.factory('pegaContas', ['$http', function($http) {
    var _getContasEntrada = function(id_empresa) {
        return $http.post("php/index.php", id_empresa);
    };

    var _setContasEntrada = function(conta) {
    }

    return {
        getContasEntrada: _getContasEntrada
        setContasEntrada: _setContasEntrada
    }
}])
```

E a minha função/método em `php` de inserção de dados está em uma classe:

```
    <?php
    function insereContaEntrada($id_empresa, $cat, $subcat, $val, $forPag, $data){
        $pdo = conectar();
        $val = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $val)));

        if($data == ''){
            $data = date("Y-m-d");
        }

        $this->insereDadosEntrada=$pdo->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO entrada (id_entrada, id_empresa, categoria, subcategoria, valor, forma_pagamento, data) 
             VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $this->insereDadosEntrada->bindValue(1, NULL);
        $this->insereDadosEntrada->bindValue(2, $id_empresa);
        $this->insereDadosEntrada->bindValue(3, $cat);
        $this->insereDadosEntrada->bindValue(4, $subcat);
        $this->insereDadosEntrada->bindValue(5, $val);
        $this->insereDadosEntrada->bindValue(6, $forPag);
        $this->insereDadosEntrada->bindValue(7, $data);
        //$this->insereDadosEntrada->execute();
        try {
            $this->insereDadosEntrada->execute();
            echo "Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print_r($this->insereDadosEntrada->errorInfo());
        }
    }
?>
```

Quero chamar esse método no angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, primeiramente você precisa informar o php qual função você deseja chamar. O método que utilizo para isso, é através de uma `action`, onde o meu link no `.factory` ficaria assim:

```
var _getContasEntrada = function(id_empresa) {
   return $http.post("php/index.php?action=insereContaEntrada",id_empresa).then( 
        function(res) { 
            console.log(res); //Verifica o que o php está retornando
            return res.data;
        },
        function(err) {alert(feedbackError);}
    );
};
```

Já no `php`, utilizo um `switch` para determinar os tipos de `action` que podem ser chamadas, deste modo:

```
switch($_GET['action']) {
    case 'insereContaEntrada': insereContaEntrada();
    break;
}

function insereContaEntrada()....
```

O processo dos dados, é feito de modo diferente (pelo menos para mim). Busco os dados vindos através da função e faço o `decode` dele, pois ele virá no modelo JSON, essa etapa fica a seu critério (acredito eu). Mas logo no inicio da função, utilize:

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Deste modo, você irá converter os dados vindos em um array que você possa trabalhar melhor. Ou então, utilize apenas o código `file_get_contents("php://input")` para pegar o dado bruto.

Ps.: Não sou muito bom na área PHP, então posso estar enganado quanto a utilizar somente o último código, mas acho que agora você já tem uma ideia do funcionamento.

---

#### Editado:

Agora que notei, o seu código tem alguns errinhos de syntax, não sei se foi só aqui ou no seu código também, mas deve ser assim:

```
.factory('pegaContas', ['$http', function($http) {
    var _getContasEntrada = function(id_empresa) {
        return $http.post("php/index.php", id_empresa);
    };

    var _setContasEntrada = function(conta) {
    };

    return {
        getContasEntrada: _getContasEntrada,
        setContasEntrada: _setContasEntrada
    }
}])
```

No bloco do return, o nome com o prefixo `_` serve apenas para você identificar qual é qual. Neste caso, o nome sem prefixo é o nome que você utiliza dentro de um controller para chamar uma função dentro do factory. O nome com prefixo é para identificar qual função dentro do factory deverá ser chamada. Apenas um `best practice` para você se organizar melhor. E deve sempre ter uma separação por vírgula, exceto a última definição.

Comment: Valeu, vou tentar...

Comment: @GustavoSevero editei minha resposta. Como você está usando php, muitas vezes o erro não está no Angular, então recomendo utilizar o return do factory daquele modo, pois assim você pode ver no console o que está acontecendo no php.

Comment: Certo..........

Comment: Não vai nada dentro desse:

var _setContasEntrada = function(conta) {
};
?

Comment: Acredito que não, essas funções não tem relação alguma uma com a outra. A função _setContasEntrada seria usada para chamar outra função do php. Se não é o seu caso, ela pode ser deletada